# Save jsondata into own .json file

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have two questions:

First i want to make api call and save the (json)data into my own json

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("{apiadress}")

with open("newone.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(response, write_file)
```

but i get a "TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable"

My Qustion is how i can save other json data my own json? the other question is, how is it possible to fetch 2 apis and store the data in my newone.json as A (data from fetch one) and B (data from fetch two) like that:

```
{
 A: {
     [data A]
    }
 B: {
     [data B]
    }
```

Comment: Are you running both API calls at the same time? If not, it might be worth considering a different format...

Comment: Also, if you want to save the json from a response, you can get it from `response.json()`...